# C: fread() is returning garbage values from a structured binary text file

Tags: c, file

I have a problem with my `fread()` it's returning garbage values instead of the values that were found in the binary text file.

These are the structures that I'm using:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define C_S 8
#define F_N 24
#define L_N 16

typedef struct nT{
    char fN[F_N],lN[L_N],mI;
}nameType;

typedef struct rec{
    nameType name;
    char course[C_S];
    int year;
    unsigned long ID;
}studRec;

typedef struct node{
    studRec student;
    struct node *link;
}*stack;

typedef enum{TRUE,FALSE}boolean;
```

And this is how I transfered an array of structures which is `studRec` into the binary file:

```
#define SIZE 3

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    int i;
    studRec records[SIZE]={
    {{"Kawin","Cheong",'E'},"BSCS",3,13104658},
    {{"Jeanne","Garciano", 'T'},"BSIT",4,1103333},
    {{"Dhiana","Oyao",'G'},"BSCS",3,1510222}
    };

    fp=fopen("studentRecords.txt","wb+");

    if(fp!=NULL){
        fwrite(records,sizeof(studRec),SIZE,fp);
        printf("\nSuccessful transfer of records.");
    }
    fclose(fp);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

And now this is my snippet for me to READ it back to the program using `fread()` and I'm displaying the variable `year` from 2nd element of the structured array `buffer`:

```
int main(){
    stack S;
    int i;
    studRec buffer[SIZE];
    FILE *fp=fopen("studentRecords.txt","wb+");

    S=initStack();
    if(S!=NULL){
        printf("\nMalloc is succesful.");
        getch();
        system("cls");
    }

    fread(buffer,sizeof(struct rec),3,fp);
    printf("\n%d",buffer[1].year);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUiYn.jpg) is what im getting:

Hopefully someone can explain to me why it's not returning the value that I'm expecting.

Comment: WTH is a *binary text file*?

Comment: What is `initStack`? It doesn’t seem to be used, so removing it will cut down on your question size and the number of potential places for you to debug.

Comment: Opening a file you want to read in `wb+` mode is probably not a good start, though.

Comment: Shouldn't fopen use `"rb"` when opening the file for reading?

Comment: Note, your writing structures to a file and reading them back is NOT guaranteed to be portable in any way. It will work for your compiler and your OS, but don't take the file created to another OS, recompile your read code there and expect it to work. You should serialize the data written to file and de-serialize as part of the read before storing the values due to the way padding his handled between compilers. (that is one of the purposes for which serialization libraries were created).

Comment: When you only want to read from a file in binary mode, use "rb"
Use data types with deterministic size in your structs e.g. int32_t from stdint.h 
To check the content of the written file to help you troubleshoot, get some 3rd party hex editor.
When you read you do not show what "SIZE" is, hopefully it is also 3
Are u reading and writing on the same platform using the same compiler, if not, that could be a cause
Make sure you use `#pragma pack(1)` (or the equivalent for your platform/compiler) to make structures on byte boundaries since otherwise your structures may be padded differently.

Comment: Your `fread` call is failing. Where are your error checks?

Comment: @melpomene It could also be the `fwrite()`.  `printf("\nSuccessful transfer of records.");`  How do you know?  You didn't bother to check the return value from `fwrite()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Sure, `fwrite` could potentially fail (e.g. full disk), but `fread` is (almost) guaranteed to fail there.

Comment: @melpomene There's no "almost" about that `fread()` failing - it *is* failing, given the code.  The questioner should look examine the file closely after running that reader code...

Comment: @AndrewHenle It could theoretically be saved by a race condition: Another process could fill the file between `fopen` and `fread`. :-)